# error compiling boost

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, windows-ce

I am trying to compile Boost 1.47 for x86 Windows CE using Visual Studio 2008 and STLPort 5.2.1. I can successfully compile for x86 Windows and ARMV4I Windows Mobile 6.5.

When I run bjam, I get this error in most every module:

```
stlport\ctype.h(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../1/ctype.h': No such file or directory
```

That line of code the error refers to in STLPort's ctype.h is:

```
#include _STLP_NATIVE_C_HEADER(ctype.h)
```

If I create a new Visual Studio project and add the lines:

```
#define STR1(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STR1(x)
#pragma message (STRINGIZE(_STLP_NATIVE_C_HEADER(ctype.h)))
```

I see: `<../X86/ctype.h>` as I would expect.

Why is boost replacing "X86" with "1"? It does not have this issue when compiling for ARMV4I Windows Mobile or x86 Windows.

**Edit**

More information. Something is very deliberately doing a string replace on "X86".

In stlport\stl\config_evc.h I added the `pragma message`s to this code:

```
#  if !defined (_STLP_NATIVE_INCLUDE_PATH)
#    if defined (_X86_)
#      if defined (_STLP_WCE_TARGET_PROC_SUBTYPE_EMULATOR)
#        define _STLP_NATIVE_INCLUDE_PATH ../Emulator
#      else
#        define _STLP_NATIVE_INCLUDE_PATH ../X86
#        pragma message (STRINGIZE(../abcdefg))
#        pragma message (STRINGIZE(../X86))
#        pragma message (STRINGIZE(_STLP_NATIVE_INCLUDE_PATH))
#      endif
```

The output is:

```
../abcdefg
../1
../1
```

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus - I am an idiot. Yes, that was (obviously) it. If you put that in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `X86` macro defined (either by one of the earlier-included headers, or from a command line) and set to `1`, so it gets expanded, like macros tend to do. `#undef X86` will get rid of it.